# removing old Settings bundle on app update

Tags: iphone

I previously used the Settings bundle on in my iPhone app but am finding it an increasingly annoying overhead to my code and have decided to move all the settings to inside my app.

When I next issue an updated app is there a way to have the old Settings Bundle removed without having to somehow ask users to re-install?

Comment: Isn't it removed when installing the updated app that doesn't have a Settings Bundle?!

Comment: Doesn't seem to, at least in dev mode for me. Closest I can get is a blank Root.plist to have a blank page in the Settings.app.  I can't seem to make it actually go away in dev, and deleting the app in dev to have a "fresh" state defeats the purpose -- I want existing users to have their app settings page removed so they only change them inside the app.

Comment: Late update.. I have the same problem. I've come to the same conclusion, an empty Root.plist at least remove available settings. Really strange that it's not possible to remove the settings.

Comment: I am asking myself the same question. I've moved the settings from bundle to in-app. Did you find out what happens when the user updates the app ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to let you know, I have also removed the Settings bundle from my app (settings are now accessible in-app).

I too was wandering what would happen when users updated, as the app remains in the settings menu when developing.

I can confirm, however, that the app successfully disappears from the settings menu once it's updated from the App Store, without having to delete and reinstall.